# Парсинг js кода в python

Tags: javascript, python, парсер

У меня есть код:

```
def get_info(link):
    html = get_html(link)
    countent = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    page = countent.select_one('div.responsive_page_content')
    scr = page.select_one('body > div.responsive_page_frame.with_header > div.responsive_page_content > div.responsive_page_template_content > script:nth-child(8)')
    #reg = re.match('var g_rgAssets = {(.*?)};', str(scr))

    print(scr)
```

и получаю ответ:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var g_rgAppContextData = {"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","icon":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg","link":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/app\/730"}};
        var g_rgAssets = {"730":{"2":{"19991923900":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"19991923900","classid":"4105682661","instanceid":"480085569"...
```

Все эти данные не статичны,т.е обычный поиск фраз не подойдёт,я думал и пробовал регулярки,но чем не совсем получилось и получал постоянный ответ None. Ломаю голову уже минут 40 над этими треклятыми регулярками. Возможно,регулярка не подойдёт,но других способов я не знаю. Будьте добры,подскажите

Comment: А как этот ответ вообще выглядит в браузере? Может лучше посмотреть в сторону selenium?

Comment: ответ в html взаключен в тэг скрипт.Селениум по возможности не юзать

Comment: Чем вызвано требование не использовать selenium? Без него задача превращается в попытку выполнить js средствами python. Весь код подобен тому, что в примере? То есть это набор переменных и объектов?

Comment: Приведите пример возвращаемых данных полностью. Для экспериментов текущий пример не пригоден

Comment: О каком ответе идёт речь? Ведь я уже дал его. Вы говорите о том,чтобы я полностью скинул ответ,который возвращает html страница,т.е весь код js?

Comment: Да, все, что вы хотите распарсить для извлечения данных. Как по вашему я должен понять, что именно вам нужно извлечь из этого кода? Телепатией не обладаю, хрустального шара не имею.

Comment: А,прошу прощение,что не уточнит. Мне нужно получить в формате json g_rgAssets,формат json - это легко,мне нужно как-то удалить что-ли остальной код,который мешает преобразовать ответ в джсон. А ответ я не могу здесь разместить,так как он слишком большой

Answer (score 0):

С большим трудом узнав, что все же нужно автору вопроса, могу предложить только продолжить "пробовать треклятые регулярки".

Допустим, ответ сервера состоит из тех двух строк, что вы предоставили в вопросе.

```py
import re
from json import loads

resp = '''<script type="text/javascript">
        var g_rgAppContextData = {"730":{"appid":730,"name":"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive","icon":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/apps\/730\/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg","link":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/app\/730"}};
        var g_rgAssets = {"730":{"2":{"19991923900":{"currency":0,"appid":730,"contextid":"2","id":"19991923900","classid":"4105682661","instanceid":"480085569"}}}};
</script>'''

# разделим ответ на отдельные строки
lines = resp.splitlines()
# для доступа к данным, используем именованную группу `json`
# подразумевается, что переменная g_rgAssets хранит валидный json
regexp = re.compile(r'^ +var g_rgAssets = (?P<json>.+);$')


# обходим построчно ответ
for l in lines:
    # если строка удовлетворяет паттерну регулярки
    if regexp.findall(l):
        # получаем объект результатов поиска регулярки по строке
        match = regexp.search(l)
        # получаем подстроку, совпадающую с именованной группой `json`
        raw = match.group('json')
        # сериализуем полученный json
        jsonData = loads(raw)
        print(type(jsonData), jsonData)
```

Здесь в регулярке для более простого доступа к данным используется именованная группа `json`.

В результате должны получить результат работы скрипта:

```
<class 'dict'> {'730': {'2': {'19991923900': {'currency': 0, 'appid': 730, 'contextid': '2', 'id': '19991923900', 'classid': '4105682661', 'instanceid': '480085569'}}}}
```

Comment: Вы не учли,что это html объект. Я преобразовал html в str и дал это на вход в ваш код,но почему-то ответа не последовало,ни ошибок ничего. Можем связаться в вами в телеграмме? Я не могу здесь размещать куски кода почему-то

Comment: 1. _Вы не учли,что это html объект._ - не имеет никакого значения. Любой html-объект приводится к строке без проблем. 2. Нет, я не даю консультаций в телеграмме. Если хотите обсудить подробности решения, можете написать мне [в этом чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116838/js---python)

Comment: Я привел его в строку с помощью str() и проверил класс и всё хорошо,дальше я заюзал ваш код и мне не выдало никакого ответа. Попробуйте реализовать это с тем кодом,что я использовал и дал выше. В get_html() находиться
def get_html(link):
    r = session.get(link)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.text

Comment: Я дал ссылку на чат - пишите туда